# Can't go downstairs in Nethack?

Tags: nethack

I have recently started playing Nethack (ie. an hour ago) and I know just about nothing more than Elbereth and commands. I have looked everywhere for the command to go down stairs to the next level but all I find is `>` and when I press that I am told

```
There is a staircase down here.
```

This is not much help. It's not that I can't find the stairways, (I know about secret passages), I just can't get *down* them!

Comment: Have you tried pressing `SHIFT + >`?  Not a Nethack player, so not sure if that'll help, but that's ADOM's "Go down stairs" button.

Comment: Yeah thats what Ive been pressing.

Comment: And The only other roguelike sort of game I play is Spelunky :L

Comment: What happens if you type `shift + >` in terminal? Maybe your keyboard layout is off. As the result you describe is caused by `look` on `:`.

Comment: "There is a staircase down here" is the message you get when getting a description of the square you're on with the '.' key. down stairs is '>'. What happens when you hit, for example, shift+w? if you get a wield weapon prompt, your shift key is not working properly. If you get a wear armour prompt, then something else is the problem.

Comment: You're right! How do I change my keyboard layout?

Comment: Steps to change the keyboard layout will vary based on the operating system you're using. As a temporary workaround while you work on figuring that out, repairing, or replacing your keyboard; you can copy from another file and paste in most implementations of Nethack. The only one I know of that this doesn't work on is the Windows Tile port. (Warning: copy and pasting of commands can sometimes lead to YASD, be careful)

Answer (score 3):

The right command to go down stairs is `>`, normally accessed as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

However, in your case the keyboard layout Nethack is using does not currently correspond to what you actually see on your keyboard. You will need to adjust the layout using the options stored in `defaults.nh` or specifically on the command line.

My version of `defaults.nh` has a number of keyboard handling options:

```
# Keyboard handling
# Different keyboard handlers can be loaded.
# Default is nhdefkey.dll but you can override that.
# Ray Chason's keyboard handler
# OPTIONS=altkeyhandler:nhraykey.dll
#
# NetHack 3.4.0 keyboard handling
# OPTIONS=altkeyhandler:nh340key.dll

# number_pad option can have an optional value of 0 (off), 1 (on), 
# or 2(on,legacy-mode) which causes 5='g', alt-5='G', alt-0='I'
OPTIONS=number_pad:1

# Note: the rest_on_space in the next line may not be
#       appropriate for a beginning NetHack player, since
#       it could result in use of a turn unintentionally.
#       If you're new to NetHack, leave it commented it out.
#OPTIONS=rest_on_space

# Finnish keyboards might need these modifications uncommented. 
# For  \, @, $, [, |
#OPTIONS=subkeyvalue:171/92
#OPTIONS=subkeyvalue:178/64
#OPTIONS=subkeyvalue:180/36
#OPTIONS=subkeyvalue:184/91
#OPTIONS=subkeyvalue:188/124
```